# Incluir link sobre Community Wiki

Tags: novo-recurso, wiki-comunitário

Quando respondemos uma pergunta, temos a opção de marcar a resposta como Community Wiki:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só acho que falta um *link* ali do lado apontando para a página que explica o que é isso, pois a descrição do *checkbox* não é auto-explicativa. Os usuários novatos não sabem o que isso significa.